# Double spacing in RMarkdown and knitting to MS Word

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown

I used the setup below to write a double spaced document but that doesn't seem to work. I did not receive any error but the knitted document is single spaced. 
I have to use MS Word because some of my collaborators work with Word only.

```
---
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
fontsize: 12pt
linespread: 2
title: "title"
author: "author"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  word_document:
  highlight: tango
bibliography: xyz.bib
biblio-style: chicago
sansfont: Times New Roman
---
```

Comment: Your output format is a word document. And yet you use Latex commands (`\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing`).

Comment: You will have to create a word template, c.f. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Thank you. Tex was my best shot.